# How to find a file from any directory

Tags: command-line, files, find

I'm trying to look for a file called **Book1**.

In my test I'm trying to look for the aforementioned file and in this test, I don't know where that file is located.

I tried `find / -iname book1` but there is no output.

How do I find my file called book1 using the command line if I don't know where the file is located?

**EDIT:**

My scenario is described in more detail below:

1. The file extension is unknown
2. The exact name (i.e. Capitalized letters, numbers, etc.) is unknown
3. The location of the file is unknown

Comment: If there is a file called `Book1`, and it is in a directory you can read, then `find / -iname book1` will find it.  Are you sure it is actually `Book1`, and not `Book1.xyz`?

Comment: The complete name of the file is Book1.gnumeric. Are you saying that I have to specify the entire name of the file? For some reason I thought, for this specific command, that all I'd need is the general name of the file. My test is trying to find a file if for example, I don't remember the file extension and only kind of know the name of the file I'm looking for. Please advise.

Comment: @don_crissti Done. Please see above Edit.

Comment: You’re mixing `find ` and `locate`. `locate` is generous, and will find anything which matches, as long as it is in its database, which is normally updated daily. `find`, in this case, is looking for a file glob, the sort of pattern you would use in `ls`. You probably mean `iname '*book1*'`. Note that the pattern must be inside quotes to stop the shell from expanding it before `find` gets to see it. Also notice that `find`, like many *nix commands, is frustratingly silent when it is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

First, an argument to `-iname` is a shell *pattern*. You can read more
about patterns in [Bash
manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html). The
gist is that in order for `find` to actually *find* a file the
filename must match the specified pattern. To make a case-insensitive
string `book1` match `Book1.gnumeric` you either have to add `*` so it
looks like this:

```
find / -iname 'book1*'
```

or specify the full name:

```
find / -iname 'Book1.gnumeric'
```

Second, `-iname` will make `find` ignore the filename case so if you
specify `-iname book1` it might also find `Book1`, `bOok1` etc. If
you're sure the file you're looking for is called `Book1.gnumeric`
then don't use `-iname` but `-name`, it will be faster:

```
find / -name 'Book1.gnumeric'
```

Third, remember about quoting the pattern as said in the [other
answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/362298/72304).

And last - are you sure that you want to look for the file
*everywhere* on your system? It's possible that the file you're
looking for is actually in your `$HOME` directory if you worked on
that or downloaded it from somewhere. Again, that may be much faster.

**EDIT**:

I noticed that you edited your question. If you don't know the full filename, capitalization and location indeed you should use something like this:

```
find / -iname 'book1*'
```

I also suggest putting `2>/dev/null` at the end of the line to hide
all `*permission denied*` and other errors that will be present if you invoke `find` as a non-root user:

```
find / -iname 'book1*' 2>/dev/null
```

And if you're sure that you're looking for a single file, and there is only a single file on your system that match 
the criteria you can tell `find` to exit after finding the first matching file:

```
find / -iname 'book1*' -print -quit 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: [`-iname` is not portable](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1P/find/)

Answer (score 9):

You may try the `locate` command. It uses a database of filenames to make searching quicker.

To search for all file matching `*book1*`, and ignoring case, you could use

```
locate -i book1
```

if you want to search for files *starting* with `book1` you will need to do the wildcard yourself:

```
locate -i 'book1*'
```

It is much faster than `find`, but is only as up-to-date as the last time the database was refreshed.

Comment: None of these produced any output for me: `locate -i after.sh`, `sudo locate -i "after.sh"`, `sudo locate -i after.sh`, `sudo locate -i '*after.sh'`

Answer (score 6):

If you know you have a file called `book1.something`, where the file location, the exact value of `something`, and the capitalization pattern of the filename are all unknown:

```
find / -iname 'book1.*'
```

If all you know for sure is that the filename contains the word `book`, you can generate a likely much larger list with

```
find / -iname '*book*'
```

---

The argument to `-name` is a shell glob pattern.  From the directory the file is in, compare:

```
$ ls Book1
ls: cannot access 'Book1': No such file or directory
$ ls Book1.*
Book1.gnumeric
```

This represents the kind of search performed by `-name`.  The `-iname` option simply allows a case-insensitive version of this.

Answer (score 2):

POSIXly,

```
LC_ALL=C find / -name '*[bB][oO][oO][kK]1*'
```

Will report the path of all files whose name contains `book1` (with any variation of case, but only considering the ASCII latin characters `bokBOK`, not the many other variations in Unicode like , , , `ᵏ`, `ₖ`, `Ｋ`, `ｋ` and all their variations with diacritics...) in all the directories you have read access to.

Answer (score 2):

With Zsh you can use glob patterns, so this works too:

```
ls -a /**/book1
```

This will find all locations where a file called `book1` lives.

In my testing, this seems to be faster than using `find`, and it also produces little to no *user permission errors* when run without root permission

See [manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_2.html).

Answer (score 1):

[ag (the silver searcher)](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) provides very fast search in files, and also has an option to search for filename:

```
>: time ag -g foo # uses heuristics to only look in desired locations
apps/vxy/src/assets/tree-content-pages/tree-page-bird/foo-illustration.jpg

real    0m0.884s
user    0m0.701s
sys     0m0.178s

>: time find . -name "*foo*"
./apps/ssr/dist/static/media/foo-illustration.jpg
./apps/vxy/dist/static/media/foo-illustration.jpg
./apps/vxy/src/assets/tree-content-pages/tree-page-bird/foo-illustration.jpg

real    0m29.744s
user    0m2.108s
sys     0m13.982s

>: time ag -ug foo # searching all files is still faster and simpler to use then find command
apps/ssr/dist/static/media/foo-illustration.jpg
apps/vxy/dist/static/media/foo-illustration.jpg
apps/vxy/src/assets/tree-content-pages/tree-page-bird/foo-illustration.jpg

real    0m16.698s
user    0m1.951s
sys     0m7.119s
```

So in my use case here it's >30 times faster if the file is not a file ignored by ag.

Answer (score 0):

For these kinds of tasks I always do : `find / -iregex '.*Book1.*'`

This form would take care of the 3 points of your scenario (`iregex` is a case insensitive rational expression, and the pattern with `.*` on both side would match any character before and after your fixed pattern of Book1 - this could obviously give you back more results than necessary but you are sure not to miss the file)

The main difference: if possible, be more restrictive than just using `/`, like trying only `/home` or so, otherwise you will descend in some directories that are not relevant (`/sys`, `/dev`, etc…)

Remember however that Unix permissions apply: if the file is in a directory for which the user running the `find` command has no access (execute) right, `find` will not be able to find it there.

Comment: iregex won't work in places like Solaris (OS was not specified) (and possibly *BSD), it is a GNU extension and is not part of [standard `find`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1P/find/)

Answer (score 0):

[Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) is a very fast and handy util to search for files and content.

To solve your problem the silver searcher command would look like this...

`ag -g Book1`

`-g PATTERN` Print filenames matching PATTERN

Answer (score 0):

`locate` and its variants tend to be a fast method.

```
# updatedb # run as root, possibly using sudo, e.g. sudo -b updatedb. If file is on the system for more than a day it should already be in the index and this can be skipped
$ locate -i book1
```

If locate is not available, you can use `find` instead. It tend to be much slower, but also much more precise.

If you have a single partition: (run as root if your user might not have access to the file)

```
$ find / -xdev -iname 'book1*' -print # If the iname extension to find is available
$ find / -xdev -print | grep -F -i /book1 # if iname is not available
```

If you do not include `-xdev` `find` searches things on other partitions, like `/proc` and `/sys`, which tend to flood your screen with errors, especially if you are not root. (Errors can be hidden by appending `2> /dev/null` at the end of the find command (the comment should be removed))

If you have multiple partitions and you don't know on which one the file is on, you can get a list with `lsblk` (on Linux-based OSes, parsing `df` output is an option otherwise) and feed that into find: (root again if you don't know if you can access the file)

```
$ find $(lsblk -O MOUNTPOINT -n | grep -F /) -xdev -iname 'book1*' -print # GNU-based OSes
$ find $(df -P|awk '$1 ~ /^\/dev/ {print $NF}') -xdev | grep -F -i book1 # Non-GNU based OSes.
```

(This is a bit fragile if any of your mountpoints have spaces in) (`df` parameters might need tuning. -P makes GNU `df` give standard POSIX output. Other versions might have other parameters or need it left out. Read your man page)

The `grep -F` excludes other things returned, like swap partitions.

In the non-GNU version, awk find devices with a mount starting with `/dev` to get real file systems and then print the last field (the mountpoint) from the `df` output.

This also assumes a bourne-like shell (`ksh` and `bash` should work. If you are using a `csh` variant, start up a [scriptable shell](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html) before you try this)

Comment: The `grep`s might be a bit noisy, [learn how to filter it](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Grep.html) [better](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html) (this should not be needed with the example, but if it is something more common that is looked for, the greps would need tuning to keep the noise levels down)

Answer (score 0):

```
find /  -type f -iname "book[0-9].*"
```